# How do I include an output file when I convert a .py file to .exe using Pyinstaller?

Tags: python, output, pyinstaller, exe

I have a Python script that looks like

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable), 'data.txt')

file = open(path, 'w')
file.write("something")
file.close()
```

When I use Pyinstaller (with the option `--onefile`), and open the resulting .exe-file, it does not seem to do anything. In particular, I cannot find a data.txt file. How do I fix this?

Comment: could you please post the whole script you want to convert?

Comment: @mousetail Of course Pyinstaller can include external data (but that's not what OP is doing here); you don't need to include the text file in your source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.path.dirname(sys.executable)` would point at the directory where Python.exe is if you were not running under Pyinstaller, and it's unlikely you'd want to write there. It's likely that under PyInstaller, it's some temporary directory.

Instead, just `'data.txt'` (or `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'data.txt')` if you want to be pedantic) would create the file in the program's current [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), which, if you just double-click on the EXE, would be the EXE's directory.